# Difference between Time-sharing computers and computers which use Round Robin scheduling algorithm?

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

So maybe I'm confused in these concepts

but i thought that time sharing computer is a computer which the processor switches between different processes quickly to achieve a good response time

but isn't this the same as Round Robin algorithm?! i mean aren't we scheduling between different processes   in Time sharing computer just like Round robin? or am i missing something here? what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent, but you are right to note a similarity.

Yes, a time sharing computer is one in which the computer switches between different processes.  The *schedular* is the part of the operating system that determines when to switch between processes, and which process to switch to.   A round robin scheduler is one particular type of scheduling strategy that could be used in a time sharing computer, but there are other possible scheduling strategies as well.

Comment: Thanks for answer, So in time sharing machine, no matter what is the priority of the process which is running, when the time slice ends the O.S will block it and run the scheduler right? now is it possible that the same process gets scheduled? if so will it still have a context switch overhead? (because if so, then there will be a lot of unnecessary overhead if we have only one process)

Comment: @JohnP, You're welcome!  This site's format doesn't work well for interactive back-and-forth questions.  I would suggest spending some time reading about operating systems and schedulers, and then if you have a single specific question, ask a new question using the 'Ask Question' button in the upper-right.  The answers to your questions will likely depend on the operating system and/or scheduler, but you should spend some time with a textbook and you'll learn more about these concepts.